# Why do I get so much random output and what does it mean?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am writing a flutter app and every time I run it I get this overwhelming amount of input and I don't know what it means

It happens with every app I run and I don't know why and haven't found information about this

I would share some code but I don't think this has to do with any specific code that I run because it happens with any app.
however, I will include an example of such output

```
E/flutter (27835): #1      BaseClient._sendUnstreamed (package:http/src/base_client.dart:169:38)
E/flutter (27835): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (27835): #2      BaseClient.get (package:http/src/base_client.dart:32:7)
E/flutter (27835): #3      get.<anonymous closure> (package:http/http.dart:46:36)
E/flutter (27835): #4      _withClient (package:http/http.dart:166:20)
E/flutter (27835): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (27835): #5      get (package:http/http.dart:46:5)
E/flutter (27835): #6      randomImages (package:google_play_recreation/main.dart:439:20)
E/flutter (27835): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (27835): #7      new Category.<anonymous closure> (package:google_play_recreation/main.dart:337:45)
E/flutter (27835): #8      __CastListBase&_CastIterableBase&ListMixin.forEach (dart:collection/list.dart:63:13)
E/flutter (27835): #9      new Category (package:google_play_recreation/main.dart:337:17)
E/flutter (27835): #10     _HomeState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:google_play_recreation/main.dart:233:68)
E/flutter (27835): #11     __InternalLinkedHashMap&_HashVMBase&MapMixin&_LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:367:8)
E/flutter (27835): #12     _HomeState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:google_play_recreation/main.dart:233:29)
E/flutter (27835): #13     _FutureBuilderState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart)
E/flutter (27835): #14     StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4012:27)
E/flutter (27835): #15     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3924:15)
E/flutter (27835): #16     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
E/flutter (27835): #17     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4085:5)
E/flutter (27835): #18     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
E/flutter (27835): #19     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
E/flutter (27835): #20     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
E/flutter (27835): #21     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4219:5)
E/flutter (27835): #22     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
E/flutter (27835): #23     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
E/flutter (27835): #24     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
E/flutter (27835): #25     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4219:5)
E/flutter (27835): #26     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
E/flutter (27835): #27     RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4817:32)
E/flutter (27835): #28     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5208:17)
E/flutter (27835): #29     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
E/flutter (27835): #30     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
E/flutter (27835): #31     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
E/flutter (27835): #32     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4085:5)
E/flutter (27835): #33     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
E/flutter (27835): #34     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
E/flutter (27835): #35     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
E/flutter (27835): #36     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4219:5)
E/flutter (27835): #37     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
E/flutter (27835): #38     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
E/flutter (27835): #39     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
E/flutter (27835): #40     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4085:5)
E/flutter (27835): #41     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
E/flutter (27835): #42     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5099:14)
E/flutter (27835): #43     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
E/flutter (27835): #44     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
E/flutter (27835): #45     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framewor
E/flutter (27835): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: Software caused connection abort, errno = 103, address = dog.ceo, port = 42980
E/flutter (27835): #0      IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:33:23)
E/flutter (27835): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (27835): #1      BaseClient._sendUnstreamed (package:http/src/base_client.dart:169:38)
E/flutter (27835): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (27835): #2      BaseClient.get (package:http/src/base_client.dart:32:7)
E/flutter (27835): #3      get.<anonymous closure> (package:http/http.dart:46:36)
E/flutter (27835): #4      _withClient (package:http/http.dart:166:20)
E/flutter (27835): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (27835): #5      get (package:http/http.dart:46:5)
E/flutter (27835): #6      randomImages (package:google_play_recreation/main.dart:439:20)
E/flutter (27835): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (27835): #7      new Category.<anonymous closure> (package:google_play_recreation/main.dart:337:45)
E/flutter (27835): #8      __CastListBase&_CastIterableBase&ListMixin.forEach (dart:collection/list.dart:63:13)
E/flutter (27835): #9      new Category (package:google_play_recreation/main.dart:337:17)
E/flutter (27835): #10     _HomeState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:google_play_recreation/main.dart:233:68)
E/flutter (27835): #11     __InternalLinkedHashMap&_HashVMBase&MapMixin&_LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:367:8)
E/flutter (27835): #12     _HomeState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:google_play_recreation/main.dart:233:29)
E/flutter (27835): #13     _FutureBuilderState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart)
E/flutter (27835): #14     StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4012:27)
E/flutter (27835): #15     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3924:15)
E/flutter (27835): #16     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
E/flutter (27835): #17     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4085:5)
E/flutter (27835): #18     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
E/flutter (27835): #19     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
E/flutter (27835): #20     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
E/flutter (27835): #21     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4219:5)
E/flutter (27835): #22     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
E/flutter (27835): #23     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
E/flutter (27835): #24     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
E/flutter (27835): #25     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4219:5)
E/flutter (27835): #26     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
E/flutter (27835): #27     RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4817:32)
E/flutter (27835): #28     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5208:17)
E/flutter (27835): #29     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
E/flutter (27835): #30     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
E/flutter (27835): #31     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
E/flutter (27835): #32     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4085:5)
E/flutter (27835): #33     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
E/flutter (27835): #34     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
E/flutter (27835): #35     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
E/flutter (27835): #36     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4219:5)
E/flutter (27835): #37     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
E/flutter (27835): #38     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
E/flutter (27835): #39     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
E/flutter (27835): #40     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4085:5)
E/flutter (27835): #41     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
E/flutter (27835): #42     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5099:14)
E/flutter (27835): #43     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
E/flutter (27835): #44     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
E/flutter (27835): #45     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framewor
E/flutter (27835): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: Software caused connection abort, errno = 103, address = dog.ceo, port = 49710
E/flutter (27835): #0      IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:33:23)
E/flutter (27835): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (27835): #1      BaseClient._sendUnstreamed (package:http/src/base_client.dart:169:38)
E/flutter (27835): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (27835): #2      BaseClient.get (package:http/src/base_client.dart:32:7)
E/flutter (27835): #3      get.<anonymous closure> (package:http/http.dart:46:36)
E/flutter (27835): #4      _withClient (package:http/http.dart:166:20)
E/flutter (27835): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (27835): #5      get (package:http/http.dart:46:5)
E/flutter (27835): #6      randomImages (package:google_play_recreation/main.dart:439:20)
E/flutter (27835): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (27835): #7      new Category.<anonymous closure> (package:google_play_recreation/main.dart:337:45)
E/flutter (27835): #8      __CastListBase&_CastIterableBase&ListMixin.forEach (dart:collection/list.dart:63:13)
E/flutter (27835): #9      new Category (package:google_play_recreation/main.dart:337:17)
E/flutter (27835): #10     _HomeState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:google_play_recreation/main.dart:233:68)
E/flutter (27835): #11     __InternalLinkedHashMap&_HashVMBase&MapMixin&_LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:367:8)
E/flutter (27835): #12     _HomeState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:google_play_recreation/main.dart:233:29)
E/flutter (27835): #13     _FutureBuilderState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart)
E/flutter (27835): #14     StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4012:27)
E/flutter (27835): #15     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3924:15)
E/flutter (27835): #16     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
E/flutter (27835): #17     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4085:5)
E/flutter (27835): #18     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
E/flutter (27835): #19     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
E/flutter (27835): #20     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
E/flutter (27835): #21     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4219:5)
E/flutter (27835): #22     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
E/flutter (27835): #23     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
E/flutter (27835): #24     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
E/flutter (27835): #25     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4219:5)
E/flutter (27835): #26     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
E/flutter (27835): #27     RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4817:32)
E/flutter (27835): #28     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5208:17)
E/flutter (27835): #29     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
E/flutter (27835): #30     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
E/flutter (27835): #31     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
E/flutter (27835): #32     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4085:5)
E/flutter (27835): #33     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
E/flutter (27835): #34     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
E/flutter (27835): #35     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
E/flutter (27835): #36     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4219:5)
E/flutter (27835): #37     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
E/flutter (27835): #38     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
E/flutter (27835): #39     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
E/flutter (27835): #40     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4085:5)
E/flutter (27835): #41     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
E/flutter (27835): #42     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5099:14)
E/flutter (27835): #43     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
E/flutter (27835): #44     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
E/flutter (27835): #45     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framewor
E/flutter (27835): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: Software caused connection abort, errno = 103, address = dog.ceo, port = 48866
E/flutter (27835): #0      IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:33:23)
E/flutter (27835): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (27835): #1      BaseClient._sendUnstreamed (package:http/src/base_client.dart:169:38)
E/flutter (27835): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (27835): #2      BaseClient.get (package:http/src/base_client.dart:32:7)
E/flutter (27835): #3      get.<anonymous closure> (package:http/http.dart:46:36)
E/flutter (27835): #4      _withClient (package:http/http.dart:166:20)
E/flutter (27835): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (27835): #5      get (package:http/http.dart:46:5)
E/flutter (27835): #6      randomImages (package:google_play_recreation/main.dart:439:20)
E/flutter (27835): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (27835): #7      new Category.<anonymous closure> (package:google_play_recreation/main.dart:337:45)
E/flutter (27835): #8      __CastListBase&_CastIterableBase&ListMixin.forEach (dart:collection/list.dart:63:13)
E/flutter (27835): #9      new Category (package:google_play_recreation/main.dart:337:17)
E/flutter (27835): #10     _HomeState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:google_play_recreation/main.dart:233:68)
E/flutter (27835): #11     __InternalLinkedHashMap&_HashVMBase&MapMixin&_LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:367:8)
E/flutter (27835): #12     _HomeState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:google_play_recreation/main.dart:233:29)
E/flutter (27835): #13     _FutureBuilderState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart)
E/flutter (27835): #14     StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4012:27)
E/flutter (27835): #15     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3924:15)
E/flutter (27835): #16     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
E/flutter (27835): #17     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4085:5)
E/flutter (27835): #18     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
E/flutter (27835): #19     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
E/flutter (27835): #20     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
E/flutter (27835): #21     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4219:5)
E/flutter (27835): #22     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
E/flutter (27835): #23     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
E/flutter (27835): #24     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
E/flutter (27835): #25     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4219:5)
E/flutter (27835): #26     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
E/flutter (27835): #27     RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4817:32)
E/flutter (27835): #28     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5208:17)
E/flutter (27835): #29     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
E/flutter (27835): #30     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
E/flutter (27835): #31     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
E/flutter (27835): #32     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4085:5)
E/flutter (27835): #33     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:
```

this app does print some text intentionally but all of those errors are weird and confusing

I don't expect to get all this output and think it indicates a problem I don't understand

EDIT: since you asked for it, [the code is on github](https://github.com/eyalkutz/Dog-API-Browser) now.

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: did you find the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

This error is due to the internet connection if the connection is slow or if you are trying to get some data from the api via internet and you are not connected to the internet than this error can occur. The same error occurred in my app also so I reconnected to the internet service and the error was removed so you can also try this.
hope this may help.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by adding internet permission and `usesCleartextTraffic` in android manifest.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    
   <application
        android:label="Test App"

        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" <!-- THIS LINE -->

        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme">
            
    </application>
</manifest>
```